# Problem with custom object in Salesforce

Tags: community

We are having a problem with a custom object (Scholarship) that is tied to Application (another custom object) and Contact. When creating a Scholarship through the Application, we receive the following message:

> 'Data Not Available The data you were trying to access could not be
>   found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system
>   error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it,
>   please look at our support page. '

The interesting thing is that it still creates the Scholarship, but the message is a distraction. I was wondering if anyone else was having a similar issue and if there is a known resolution. Thank you

Comment: How is an application created, through the standard Salesforce UI or is it a Visualforce page?

Comment: Can you perform this action as System Administrator without error?  If so you can narrow the issue down to profile security.

Comment: We are not having a problem with the application.  The issue is with the creation of the scholarship, which is done online through Salesforce.  I was able to replicate the issue in a test environment as System Administrator.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that the Application is a child of the Contact as well.

Comment: When you say online through Salesforce, you mean through the standard salesforce UI?  Not a VF page, or through a Vf Site or community page?

Comment: What is Scholarship's relationship to the other two objects? For an application like this, I'd have normally expected Contact to be a look-up from Application rather than Application being a child of Contact. You might look at the 1 to many vs many to 1, many to many and/or parent child relationships you've established. Are there any junction objects in the schema (particularly ones where that's their sole purpose)? Its very possible that one of them could be broken.

Comment: This isn't nearly enough information to answer this question.  Please elaborate with code snippets (triggers, pages, controllers involved, etc), workflow rules, object relationships, etc. We have no way to know what is happening.

Comment: The Visualforce pages we are using are the standard pages the SalesForce sets up when you create a new object. Here is a typical process flow:
1) Create the Contact - Save
2) Receive the application information either electronically (which will be an upload through DemandTools) or hard copy (which will be a manual entry) - Save
3) Receive the Scholarship information and create the Scholarship off the Application manually - Save
It is after the save in the 3rd step that causes the error to show.

Comment: Please edit your original post with any additional information you provide so everyone can see it. Being honest, what you've just told us, is of little help to me. I recommend you open up the Schema Editor, isolate the three objects, drag them close together, then take a screen shot to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was a little tricky and would have been impossible to answer without knowing that there was a custom button tied to the Scholarship object.  The button was built to bring along the application and student reference as prepopulated fields on the scholarship and take you back to the application once you saved the scholarship.  The problem was that there was a contact id hard-coded in the code.  Once the code was fixed, the process worked as expected.